# Use Server.MapPath to load external files

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, load, server.mappath

I want to load an XML file which is in D: drive. This is what I used

```
doc.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/D:/Employee.xml"));
```

But it gives me an error whenever I try to run my program:

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

I read it somewhere that Server.MapPath can be used only for webpages or web apps. I made a form in asp.net using c#.

Why am I getting this error?

This is my code:

```
 private void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("D:\\Employee.xml");
        XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes("Employee");
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            sb.Append("Name: ");
            //Select the text from a single node, “Title” in this case
            sb.Append(node.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText);
            sb.Append("EmpID: ");
            sb.Append(node.SelectSingleNode("EmpID").InnerText);
            sb.Append("Dept: ");
            sb.Append(node.SelectSingleNode("Dept").InnerText);
            sb.Append("");
        }
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
    }
```

I have made a form in VS 2008. Saved the details in an XML file. And now want to display the output.

Comment: Which code line throws exception?

Comment: Last one. Response.Write. I want to basically display the output either in the form or in a new page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not load directly:

```
doc.Load("D:\\Employee.xml");
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks. But I was using : `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sb.ToString());` method to display it. and Now that is showing an error! :/

Comment: @syrion: Seem you use HttpContext.Current in different thread?

Comment: Actually I made a form in vs 2008. So I'm pretty confused on how to load and display the output. I'll just edit my question and write the complete code.

Comment: @Syrion: could you test it again?

Answer (score 2):

In a desktop application there is not such HttpContext.Current, that's why you get the NullReferenceException. Instead, use

```
doc.Load("D:/Employee.xml");
```